# How to remove memory directions from an empty vector

Tags: c, memory, vector, directions

I'm starting into C programming and my english is not the best, so I'll try to explain myself the best i can...

I was trying to do a program that generates random numbers, pairs and odd numbers, and saves those numbers into two different vectors...

So it looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ARRAYSIZE 6

void main()
{
    int randomNumber, position, pairVector[ARRAYSIZE], oddVector[ARRAYSIZE];
    srand(time(NULL)); 

    for (position = 0; position < ARRAYSIZE; position++)
    {
        randomNumber = rand() % 49 + 0;
        if (randomNumber % 2 == 0)
            pairVector[position] = randomNumber;
        else
            oddVector[position] = randomNumber;
    }

    // Loop to print all the pair random numbers 
    for (position = 0; position < ARRAYSIZE; position++)
    {
        if(pairVector[position] >= 0)
            printf("%d ", pairVector[position]);
    }
    // Separation of the pair and odd numbers
    printf("\n\n\n");

    // Loop to print all the odd random numbers 
    for (position = 0; position < ARRAYSIZE; position++)
    {
        if (oddVector[position] >= 0)
            printf("%d ", oddVector[position]);
    }
}
```

As u can see, I have 2 loops to print pairs and odd numbers, this numbers are printed with 2 loops, so here goes my question...

Without the condition >= 0 in the vector inside the loop, I got printed some memory directions (because if I have a size of 6 ints but only 3 numbers (pair or odd), the other 3 directions are printed too)... What can I do to remove those directions from the printed vector without the condition? Maybe pointers?

Thanks in advice and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: An example of what im talking about without if conditions... output: 

28 24 32 48 42 -858993460 (this would be the pair vector)


-858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 17 (this would be the odd vector) 

I want to remove the memory direction "-858993460".

Comment: The right word for `pair` would be `even`.

Comment: Preinitialize the arrays with "illegal" numbers (>48), as your random number is never taking value greater than 48. So you can detect the invalid entries. You will need a condition anyway. Or you will need a completely different data structure, probably dynamic one. Or, alternatively, you can add some offset to either even or odd entries in the *same* array. For example if you add `50` to even numbers, you can always tell the entry is even, and then subtract `50` to restore the value.

Comment: Thanks it worked! I'll need to work into another data structure if I want my vectors to contain all the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the both arrays elements at 0

```
for(position = 0; position < ARRAYSIZE; position++)
   pairVector[position] = 0;
```

do it for the both arrays and your arrays will be filled with 0 (zeroes), next fill up your arrays with rand numbers, so you will have something like

example: 24, 22, 58, 0, 0, 0

when you want to printout array, just go something like

```
for(position = 0; position < ARRAYSIZE; position++)
{
    if(pairVector[position] != 0)
         printf("%d ", pairVector[position]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that you don't know when the arrays are gonna be filled completely, I suggest you to do a while loop until the both arrays are filled.

```
void main()
{
int randomNumber, position, pairVector[ARRAYSIZE], oddVector[ARRAYSIZE];
srand(time(NULL)); 
int pairIndex, oddIndex;
pairIndex = oddIndex = 0;  // you will increment them once you find a number for regarding array

while ((pairIndex < ARRAYSIZE) || (oddIndex < ARRAYSIZE) )
{
    randomNumber = rand() % 49 + 0;
    if (randomNumber % 2 == 0){
        if (pairIndex<ARRAYSIZE) 
           pairVector[pairIndex++] = randomNumber;
    }
    else{
        if (oddIndex<ARRAYSIZE) 
            oddVector[oddIndex++] = randomNumber;
    }
}

// Loop to print all the pair random numbers 
for (position = 0; position < ARRAYSIZE; position++)
{
    if(pairVector[position] >= 0)
        printf("%d ", pairVector[position]);
}
// Separation of the pair and odd numbers
printf("\n\n\n");

// Loop to print all the odd random numbers 
for (position = 0; position < ARRAYSIZE; position++)
{
    if (oddVector[position] >= 0)
        printf("%d ", oddVector[position]);
}
}
```

In your approach the loop went through only 6 times and for sure one or both arrays could be incomplete. In the solution above you will fill both arrays and then you print them.

Comment: Thank you all guys, so resuming, while programming u can't "detect" when there's a memory direction and not print that position right? U gotta initialize both arrays to any value so those values are those that we need to "detect" and not print... Thanks you all.